# Visual Studio 2012 and Web Essentials 2012 crashes on builds

Tags: visual-studio, web-essentials

I've installed Web Essentials 2.5.1 and typescript 0.8.3; however, now Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate immediately crashes upon builds. The crashes stop if I uninstall Web Essentials. Does anyone have any suggestions to remedy the crashes? Thanks.

Comment: And when you have the error log, you can report a bug here: http://madskristensen.net/contact.aspx?subject=Web%20Essentials%202012%20bug

Comment: VTC. Without any further info, this is too localised to answer, or to be of any future use.

Comment: It's pretty consistent. If I turn off the preview pane for ts files I get the an error has occurred because of an extension. But if I have the preview pane turned on I get a fatal crash that takes studio out. If Essentials is uninstalled there are no problems.

Comment: Plus if I open the file without the project/solution everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

It could be the error we just encountered when pulling in Wordpress/PHP project. If BOTH the **.css** and **.less** files are *Include in project*, the build will crash. If this happens

1. Right-click the **.css** file and *Exclude from project*
2. Delete the **.css** file from Explorer
3. Save the project
4. Double click the **.less** file to open in an editor
5. Change something and *save* the **.less** file.
6. Save the project

At this point the **.css** file and **.min.css** files will be generated and added to the project as dependent files like they would have been in a normal project.

If you're looking at the project's **.csproj** file, it goes from looking like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="test.less" />
    <Content Include="test.css" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="test.less" />
    <Content Include="test.css">
        <DependentUpon>test.less</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="test.min.css">
        <DependentUpon>test.less</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```